Why does except Exception appear to not be catching an exception?
The code below raises two exceptions: A ValueError and a library specific ApplicationError. The ValueError is still being printed to the console. Why is the except block not suppressing its output?
from pyomo.common.errors import ApplicationError
from pyomo.environ import SolverFactory

try:
    solver = SolverFactory("glpk", executable="bad_path")
    if solver.available():
        print("GLPK solver is available.")
    else:
        print("GLPK solver not available.")
except (ValueError, ApplicationError) as e: 
# except Exception as e: # also doesn't work 
    print(f"Caught {type(e).__name__}")

Console output:
> python .\test_pyomo_glpk_solver.py
WARNING: Failed to create solver with name '_glpk_shell': Failed to set
executable for solver glpk. File with name=bad_path either does not exist or
it is not executable. To skip this validation, call set_executable with
validate=False.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\env\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 148, in __call__
    opt = self._cls[_name](**kwds)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".\env\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\solvers\plugins\solvers\GLPK.py", line 92, in __init__
    SystemCallSolver.__init__(self, **kwargs)
  File ".\env\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\solver\shellcmd.py", line 66, in __init__
    self.set_executable(name=executable, validate=validate)
  File ".\env\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\solver\shellcmd.py", line 115, in set_executable
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Failed to set executable for solver glpk. File with name=bad_path either does not exist or it is not executable. To skip this validation, call set_executable with validate=False.
Caught ApplicationError


issubclass(ValueError, Exception), so except Exception: should catch it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy

Note that your code doesn’t appear in the traceback, so it’s not originating from that code.

@jonrsharpe, it is not catching the error.  I can replicate the issue.

...yes, it does. You're reaching print(msg) in the except block. Step through with a debugger.

@Salvatore, turns out it is a logger.warning that is showing an exception.  See my answer for how to suppress it.

What's the evidence that the ApplicationError is raised? If the first WARNING is the evidence, it appears something else catches and "handles" the error. There is no more ApplicationError for you to catch.

@chepner The last line of the console output is the error message printed from the except block. I'll edit to make it more clear.

You can't raise two exceptions "simultaneously"; the first exception prevents any code (including what would raise the second exception) from running. Execution does not resume until the first exception is caught.

What you are seeing is not actually the error bubbling up, it is a logger.warning that captured the error and is showing it. See the line here in the Pyomo code
You can suppress it by changing the logging level for that module.
from pyomo.common.errors import ApplicationError
from pyomo.environ import SolverFactory
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('pyomo.opt')
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

try:
    solver = SolverFactory("glpk", executable="bad_path")
    if solver.available():
        print("GLPK solver is available.")
    else:
        print("GLPK solver not available.")
except ApplicationError as e:
    print(f"Caught {type(e).__name__}: {e}")


Ahhh great catch. The "WARNING" should have tipped me off, but I missed that since it's also printing the normal exception contents.
